# How to stretch a bitmap image to some specific Co Ordinates using WIN32 core and VC++?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I just want to create a program which crops an image and sends the cropped image to some remote location.

I have loaded the image using BitBlt(). I dont know, How to uniformly display all the images ? all of same size. stretching is allowed. I have created a static control and now I want to display all the images inside this static control only...

I am able to display images using STM_SETIMAGE, but the problem is that images are not displayed uniformly. So I thought to resize the images before sending them to SendMessage(). I have tried BitBlt() and StretchBlt() but I dont know  why nothing works in my code.

[The detailed Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800167/why-the-image-is-not-displayed/)

Any Help, will be appreciated...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try using StretchBlt() instead of BitBlt(). It allows you to specify the source and destination rectangles which will crop and stretch the image.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145120(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145120%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: You can also call SetStretchBltMode/halftone prior to this if your unhappy with the quality

Comment: thanks for your help,  I have created a Rectangle using Rectangle() how do I get its DC...

Comment: The rectangle itself doesn't have a DC, you draw a rectangle on a DC. You can get the DC for the client area of a window by calling GetDC().

Comment: thanks @Ryand I tried using StretchBlt() but landed to another problem which I have written in a separate thread  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800167/why-the-image-is-not-displayed)

Answer (score 1):

If you store your image internally as a DIB, using [StretchDIBits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() would be my recommendation.

Comment: Thanks buddy,I have stored image in a HBITMAP object.... can I convert it to DIB ?

Comment: Create a memory DC for `CreateDIBSection()` to use, select your HBITMAP into another memory DC, then blit from the HBITMAP's DC into the DIB's DC.