# Displaying image in WIN32, Why its not displayed?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I want to load a BitMap image in a pic box I created inside a window...picBoxDisp is created using following mechanism..

```
picBoxDisp = CreateWindow("STATIC", "image box",
                      WS_VISIBLE |WS_CHILD | SS_BITMAP |WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER,
                      50, 50, 250, 300, hwnd , (HMENU)10000, NULL, NULL);
```

Now Next I created a hBitmap object and loaded an image in to it...

```
hBitmap = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(NULL,szFileName,IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,
                              LR_LOADFROMFILE| LR_DEFAULTSIZE);

SendMessage(picBoxDisp,STM_SETIMAGE,(WPARAM) IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM) NULL);   
//now assign the new image

//Create a compatible DC for the original size bitmap, for example originalMemDc.
HDC originalDC = GetDC((HWND)hBitmap);
HDC originalMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(originalDC);
if(originalMemDC==NULL){
    MessageBox(NULL,"Problem while creating DC.","Error",MB_OK);
}
//Select hBitmap into originalMemDc.
SelectObject(originalMemDC,hBitmap);

//Create a compatible DC for the resized bitmap, for example resizedMemDc.
HDC picBoxDC = GetDC(picBoxDisp);
HDC resizedMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(picBoxDC);

//Create a compatible bitmap of the wanted size for the resized bitmap,
HBITMAP hResizedBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(picBoxDC,250,300);

//Select hResizedBitmap into resizedMemDc.
SelectObject(resizedMemDC,hResizedBitmap);

//Stretch-blit from originalMemDc to resizedMemDc.
//BitBlt(resizedMemDC,0,0,250,300,originalMemDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);

BITMAP bmp_old,bmp_new;
GetObject(hBitmap,sizeof(bmp_old),&bmp_old);
GetObject(hResizedBitmap,sizeof(bmp_new),&bmp_new);

StretchBlt ( resizedMemDC,0,0,bmp_new.bmWidth,bmp_new.bmHeight,
            originalMemDC,0,0,bmp_old.bmWidth,bmp_new.bmHeight,
            SRCCOPY);
////De-select the bitmaps.

if((resizedMemDC==NULL)||(hResizedBitmap == NULL)) {
    MessageBox(NULL,"Something is NULL","Error",MB_OK);
}
else
    //Set hResizedBitmap as the label image with STM_SETIMAGE
    SendMessage(picBoxDisp,STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM) IMAGE_BITMAP,(LPARAM) hResizedBitmap);
```

**I just cant understand, why the above code is not working ?**

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstood the `STM_SETIMAGE` usage. Do this:

```
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)::LoadImage(NULL, szFileName, IMAGE_BITMAP,
                               0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE| LR_DEFAULTSIZE);

if (hBitmap != NULL)
{
    ::SendMessage(picBoxDisp, STM_SETIMAGE,
                  (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)hBitmap); 
}
```

**EDIT:** If you want to resize the bitmap before setting it as the label image, then follow this scheme for the simplest possible way to do it (with sub-optimal quality in the resized image...):

1. Create a compatible DC for the original size bitmap, for example `originalMemDc`.
2. Select `hBitmap` into `originalMemDc`.
3. Create a compatible DC for the resized bitmap, for example `resizedMemDc`.
4. Create a compatible bitmap of the wanted size for the resized bitmap, for example `hResizedBitmap`.
5. Select `hResizedBitmap` into `resizedMemDc`.
6. Stretch-blit from `originalMemDc` to `resizedMemDc`.
7. De-select the bitmaps.
8. Set `hResizedBitmap` as the label image with `STM_SETIMAGE`

Should work!

Comment: thanks @Johann Gerell..I tried above code but problem was that all the images were being displayed of different sizes... some looks bigger and better while some others are displayed in a corner (smaller images)... I just wanted to stretch all the images to same size.

Comment: @ArtsitOfProgramming: Please see my updated answer with bitmap resizing logic.

Comment: Thanks @Johann Gerell, Can you plz help me in step 4 and step 7. for the resizedMemDC I have used following code, plz let me know if this is wrong                                                       HDC picBoxDC = GetDC(picBoxDisp);  //picBoxDisp is the handle of static control                                                                     
             HDC resizedMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(picBoxDC);

Comment: @James Gerell, I dont know how to proceed for the step 4 and step 7... I want the new of exactly same size as picBoxDisp Control.... thanks buddy for ur help,

Comment: @ArtsitOfProgramming: I already wrote how to do it: *Create a compatible bitmap of the wanted size for the resized bitmap*, like this: `hResizedBitmap = ::CreateCompatibleBitmap(picBoxDC, 250, 300)`. You select/deselct a bitmap into/out of a DC with `::SelectObject`.

Comment: @James Gerell, Please see the editing I did in the code. the Program is still not working and surprisingly there is not even any error. I am confused and stucked. Thanks Buddy,

Comment: @Johann Gerell : the code is finally working.... you provided valuable help.... thanks for all that kindness... I ws able to proceed in this code bcoz of ur help.... thanks once again..

Answer (score 2):

The static control won't stretch the image to its size. You could use SS_CENTERIMAGE but it either clips or fills the empty space with the color of the top left pixel (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/b7w5x74z.aspx). You'd have to stretch the bitmap yourself before sending it to the static control.

Comment: thanks @Marius Bancila... that is why I was trying to stretch the image using StretcBlt() but I think I am lost somewhere...

Comment: Right, but you are not sending the stretched bitmap to the control, or at leas you're not showing that code. You have this call to CreateCompatibleDC(hdc); what is hdc there? Why don't you create a compatible memory device context from hpicBoxDc?

Comment: Please see the edited code, I tried everything suggested in this thread.. but the program is still not working nor it is showing any error..

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to assign an image to a static control, so you don't need to draw the image but to set the image on it.

```
// set the image
HBITMAP hold = (HBITMAP)SendMessage(hpicBoxDc, STM_SETIMAGE, IMAGE_BITMAP, LPARAM(hBitmap));

// clear the old image
if(hold && hold != hBitmap)
   DeleteObject(hold );
```

Comment: thanks @cbx..I tried above code but problem was that all the images were being displayed of different sizes... some looks bigger and better while some others are displayed in a corner (smaller images)... I just wanted to stretch all the images to same size.

Comment: @ArtsitOfProgramming A static control won't be able to dynamically resize the bitmap for you without resizing itself. You would have to use create it on a memoryDC and stretch it over the control.

Comment: That is what I am trying to achieve, Tried everything but the code is still not working... (Please see the edited code).